# How can I create a smudge tool in Actionscript?

Tags: graphics, actionscript, bitmap

I'm looking for some code on how to make a smudge tool in Actionscript.  The best I have found is this [old entry here,](http://actionsnippet.com/?p=1803) but I imagine other better options exist.

Thank you.

edit:
Assuming that better snippets don't exist.  Here is the code as I have it now:

```
import flash.events.Event;

[SWF(backgroundColor = 0xCCCCCC)]
var canvas:BitmapData = new BitmapData(400,200,true, 0xFFFFFFFF);
addChild(new Bitmap(canvas));
 
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.load(new URLRequest("http://actionsnippet.com/wp-content/chair.jpg"));
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
function onComplete(evt:Event):void{
    canvas.draw(loader);
}
 
var brush:Shape = new Shape();
var diameter:Number = 40;
var radius:Number = diameter / 2;
var matrix:Matrix = new Matrix();
 var smudgeOn:Boolean = false;
var brushAlpha:BitmapData = new BitmapData(diameter, diameter, true, 0x00000000);
drawRadial();
brushAlpha.draw(brush);
 
var xp:Number = 0, yp:Number = 0, px:Number = 0, py:Number = 0;
var dx:Number, dy:Number;
 stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, turnOnSmudge);
 stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, turnOffSmudge);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onLoop);
function onLoop(evt:Event):void {
    xp = mouseX - radius;
    yp = mouseY - radius;
    dx = xp - px;
    dy = yp - py;
    if(smudgeOn){   
        canvas.copyPixels(canvas,
                    new Rectangle(px, py, diameter, diameter),
                    new Point(xp, yp), brushAlpha, new Point(0,0), true);
    }
    px = xp;
    py = yp;
}
function turnOnSmudge(e:Event){
    smudgeOn = true;
}
function turnOffSmudge(e:Event){
    smudgeOn = false;
}  

function drawRadial():void{
    matrix.createGradientBox(diameter, diameter, 0, 0, 0);
    with (brush.graphics){
        beginGradientFill(GradientType.RADIAL, [0xFFFFFF, 0xFFFFFF], [1,0], [0, 255], matrix, SpreadMethod.PAD);
        drawCircle(radius, radius, radius);
    }
}
```

However, if you smudge in the same place for a long time, the areas becomes black, instead of remaining the color of the point beneath the cursor.  Are there better algorithms to create a smudge tool which do not suffer from the limitations of the code above?

Comment: Share some code. Stackoverflow is not a tutorial website.

Comment: @RST where do you suggest I ask about the existence of code or not, if not here?

Comment: Familiarize yourself with Actionscript on the Adobe website or other on line resources. Put some code together. Show it here in case you can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You put a timer and keep drawing the area you smudge, drawing it where the mouse is in that timer's moment. You could apply a bit of a blur. You can also play with the size of the smudge area.

Comment: How does that make it look smudged? What am I drawing where?

Comment: you smudge a circle of the target of course. are you trying to make photoshop in flash?

Comment: I'm trying to make a photoshop in flash who's only function is to smudge things.

Comment: are you saying that a smudge is basically a clone that is close by?

Comment: think about it, isn't it really what smudge does?take a wet paper, smudge it with your finger. the area under your finger remains constant, and while you drag, the presence of your finger does the smudge.